# Unable to resize Windows 7 Search box in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-search

I have the same problem as what's listed here: http://www.sevenforums.com/44531-post1.html

I can't modify the size of the search box in Windows Explorer. It's way too big. The double arrows appear, but nothing happens when I drag the arrows to try to make the box smaller.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you check out this http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3339-windows-explorer-address-search-bar-change-size.html

Comment: Coincidentally enough, I wish I could put MORE stuff beside the Search folders. . .

Comment: Sorry, but I know how to do basic stuff in Windows, and more. I am actually the Network Admin in a mixed WinXP and Win7 shop. But there's something actually wrong with my Win7 laptop, because even though I drag the double arrows, nothing happens.

Comment: OK, I have a fix for this to anyone who is still having this problem. It will be posted shortly and it is quite a (programatic) hack!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed itself (maybe after the August patch-Tuesday patches?).

Answer (score 1):

Open Computer, click `Organize>Layout>Menu bar` to expose the menu bar. Then right click the open space next to "Help", and uncheck "Lock the toolbars". Now, you can resize the search box by grabbing the bar just to the left of it, but to the right of the circular arrows.

[image]

Comment: At first, I tried this by just holding down the ALT key to expose the menu bar, but it closed the "Lock the toolbars", so I had to edit to show the Menu bar persistently.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, at least for me.

Comment: I just realized you said you are a sysadmin above, so you can probably tell another fellow professional if you look at my answers, and if you would not mind a second set of eyes looking at it in a TeamViewer session, send an e-mail to the address in my profile. I really think I could figure this out easily if I can put my hands on it, but that is up to you. Please let me know either way as I will delete this message tomorrow.

Comment: Here there,Sorry, I never saw your reply until now (funny, I didn't get an email notice about it). In any case, it has resolved itself somehow (maybe through a patch Tuesday patch??). <shrug> so who knows what it was then! I'll close this now.. :)

Comment: After doing everything in the given answer+closing all file explorer windows and reopening it fixed it for me. Maybe worth adding it to the answer.